# Is AWS S3 optimal for storing a large time series data?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-design, time-series

So I have a pretty good experience with using AWS.

I want to use S3 to store large time series data for cost saving reasons.
It'll be a large data because it's gathering data in every minute interval. So i've thought of using two options.

The data is a collection of sensors, and behaviors data that require analysis. And using S3 is a must (aside from Hadoop or other system), simply for cost reasons. And it will be a minute data of roughly 7 years, so the number of rows will be roughly minimum of 3.6 million rows.

Option A: create a single csv file into a bucket, and use S3 select to query specific items

Pros: more flexibility in the query condition and better management of the files. Better management of null/None values.

Cons: Because i need to store the data every minute, that means I need to download the said csv file into the local system, append the new minute data, and then insert into the s3 which isn't highly scalable for my need (i.e. as the said csv becomes very large, there will be a latency and consistency issue)

Option B: for every minute, create a json file and format the file name to include the timestamp, and insert into the S3 bucket

Pros: theoretically doesn't need an additional AWS SDK to query since if I need some data from timestamp A to timestamp B, i could query them based on the URL. Also, creating more datapoint is more scalable since the number of files within the directory allowed is unlimited, and doesn't require downloading a large file to be able to insert a data

Cons: inflexibility in query conditions. i.e. if I only need a certain data value from timestamp A, to timestamp B, I would need to first collect all the data from the time range and then filter them, which would also mean managing null/None values will be harder. Also, because the said bucket will have many files, there will be an issue of managing the files especially when the files must be migrated to somewhere else. Also, even though S3 allows unlimited number of files, I wonder how it would work in practice in terms of cost and the actual latency ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Working backwards, the first question is how you would like to query the data stored in the S3 bucket.

#### How to Query data

Yes, you can use S3 Select to query a single file, but **what if you want to query *lots* of files?**

A great option is to **use Amazon Athena to query data stored in Amazon S3**. Athena can query multiple S3 objects in parallel using normal SQL. First, create a table that defines the columns and point it to a 'location' in S3. Then, when you run a Query, Athena will look at all files in that location, including subdirectories.

You can also **partition the data** into subdirectories. When an Athena table is configured for partitioning, it can automatically skip-over partitions that do not have the desired data. For example, if you have one partition per month and you want to query one month of data, it only needs to look at the objects in one subdirectory.

Athena works best with Snappy-compressed Parquet files. They are fast to process, small in size to lower storage costs and, best of all, Athena charges for the amount of data read from disk, so compressed data in columnar format is rather cheap to query.

#### How to Store data

Thus, an optimal format for storing the data is Snappy-Compressed Parquet files, partitioned into subdirectories. Preferably, rather big files 200MB to 1GB in size. Any smaller and you have too much overhead accessing the files. Any bigger and Athena can't process them efficiently in parallel.

Parquet is a columnar format that compresses quite nicely.

#### How to convert data

So, how do you convert "once a minute" data into fewer, larger files?

You could use a service like Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose, which can receive streaming data and then collate it into larger files every *n* minutes or every *n* GBs. However, the output format is not optimal.

Likely, you're best-off running a job each day that takes the small files you currently have and combines them into larger parquet files. Athena can help you do that by selecting data from a source table/location and inserting it into a destination table. (Look online for advice about how to best achieve this).

#### Bottom Line

- Combine the data into fewer, larger files
- Use Snappy-compressed parquet format for fast performance, preferably partitioned into sub-directories
- Use Amazon Athena to define tables and query data